# Windows Command line: Is there any way to check syntax of bat file without actually running it?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file, syntax

Windows Command line: Is there any way to check syntax of bat file without actually running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately a good and extensive checker doesn't really exist.

The only one I was able to locate is
[BatCodeCheck](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/battech_batcodecheck.php),
which dates from 2014 and which checks for only a limited number of errors.

Comment: All the more reason to switch to a real language like PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try to run the .bat in a sandbox enironment. I haven't tried it myself, but start the cmd.exe in a sandbox programm and then try to execute the bat file.

This might work if all necessary files are present.

Comment: I am looking for a similar solution, because running my bat file only gives an "invalid syntax" error. Wish it would tell me what the invalid syntax was, or at least what ln/char it's at